# coTurn is running on ubuntu but no relay candidate on trickleICE

Tags: ubuntu, webrtc, firewall, iptables, coturn

I have implemented webrtc which works on similar network. On different network the remote stream comes as black screen. As I understand I need to configure  turn server and I choose to use  coturn on ubuntu. I have configured it and it  shows running.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGJZm.png)

My turnserver fig looks like this

```html
listening-port=3478
tls-listening-port=5349

listening-ip=LOCALIP
listening-ip=DOCKERINETADDRESS


relay-ip=LOCALIP
relay-ip=DOCKERINETADDRESS

external-ip=PUBLICIP1/LOCALIP
external-ip=PUBLICIP1/DOCKERINETADDRESS
external-ip=PUBLICIP2/LOCALIP
external-ip=PUBLICIP2/DOCKERINETADDRESS




min-port=49152
max-port=65535


realm=myrealm.com
server-name=mydomain.com

#lt-cred-mech
#userdb=/etc/turnuserdb.conf

#oauth
user=youruser:yourpassword

# use real-valid certificate/privatekey files
cert=/etc/ssl/cert.pem
pkey=/etc/ssl/pkey.key

fingerprint
cipher-list="DEFAULT"
no-stdout-log

no-cli
no-sslv3
no-tlsv1
```

I am trying to trickleICE (https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/ ) using following options but none of them gives me relay candidate.

- turn:PUBLICIP?:3478transport=udp[user:password]
- turn:PUBLICIP:3478?transport=tcp[user:password]
- turn:PUBLICIP:3478[user:password]

  I am assuming its my firewall which is preventing the connection. I have used following IPTABLE rules to open port :
- -A INPUT -i docker0 -j ACCEPT
- -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 3478 -j ACCEPT
- -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 5349 -j ACCEPT
- -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 49152:65535 -j ACCEPT
- -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 49152:65535 -j ACCEPT
- -A INPUT -i docker0 -j ACCEPT

Anyone can give me pointers of how to access my coturn service to get relay candidates. It would helpful to know how to configure iptables /firewall for coturn.